# How to show that $\chi(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\chi(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt}$ is complex valued if $\chi(t) = 0$ for $t<0$

Tags: fourier-analysis

The question is physics related, but my issue stems from the math so I figured this was an appropriate place. I'm looking at the (electric) susceptibility $\chi$, in both the time $t$ and frequency $\omega$ domains. From physical reasoning (causality) one knows that in the time domain $\chi(t) = 0$ for all times $t < 0$, and also that it is a real function, $\chi(t) = \chi(t)^*$.

Okay, so lets go into the frequency domain! We define $\chi(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\chi(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt}$

Now, my textbook says that because we have that because the time domain susceptiblity is zero valued for all $t<0$, we **must** have a complex valued $\chi(\omega)$. I feel like this should be a trivial consequence of the above definitions (and the fourier transform), but I just don't see it. Can someone help me on the way?

Comment: Note: $\chi(t)=0$ for all $t$ gives a real-valued result.

Comment: $FT[\chi](\omega)$ is complex valued, its complex argument is not constant : because if it was then $e^{i\theta} FT[\chi](\omega)$ would be real for all $\omega$ so that $e^{i\theta}\chi(t)$ would be even : $(e^{i\theta} \chi(-t))^* = e^{i \theta} \chi(t)$

Comment: @Joel You are completely right, I should say for non-trivial time domain susceptibility, my mistake.

Comment: Hm, I've found a possible solution myself, but it's not super complicated so perhaps it doesn't really warrant an answer. Should I close the question instead? I'm not entirely sure what the policy is.

Comment: the fourier (or inverse) transform of a real valued function is even : $F(-\omega) = F(\omega)^*$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that is true. But if $F(\omega)$ was real in what you write, that would still be true, right?

Comment: I used the converse : if your fourier transform had a constant complex argument, then your $\chi(t)$ function would be "even" in the sense I wrote. that's all we can say about that fourier transform for now and that's what your textbook meant.

Comment: @user1952009 Right, so you mean that that is in conflict with causality. That makes sense.